# datetime splitting a frame in rstudio

Tags: r, date, datetime

```
Data_Assignment$timestamp
[1] "[29:23:53:25]" "[29:23:53:36]" "[29:23:53:53]" "[29:23:54:15]"
[5] "[29:23:54:16]" "[29:23:54:18]" "[29:23:54:19]" "[29:23:54:19]"
```

Here is a sample of the dataframe I already tried to add 1995-08 by using a for loop, and splitting the data by : but I kinda stuck at the end when preparing a format, and the for loop is ommitting lots of rows

You will see entries such as “[29:23:53:25]”, where the 29th refers to the day of the month in August 1995, and the rest of the data refers to the time of the day 23:53:25 (in hours, minutes and seconds). Convert the time into year, month, day, hour, min and seconds format so that it reads as “1995-08-29 23:52:25”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need a for loop for this, and there are different options to pursue depending on what you need.

One option is to use `stringr` and `lubridate`. The former package has `str_extract_all` to extract all the numbers from your strings. There are alternatives to consider if you want to use specific regex patterns.

You can use `lubridate` to build your datetime string if you'd like. You can `paste` in your selected year, month, and the values for the rest (date, hours, minutes, seconds).

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

nums <- apply(str_extract_all(vec, "\\d+", simplify = TRUE), 2, as.numeric)

ymd_hms(paste0("1995-08-", nums[,1], " ", nums[,2], ":", nums[,3], ":", nums[,4]))
```

**Output**

```
[1] "1995-08-29 23:53:25 UTC" "1995-08-29 23:53:36 UTC" "1995-08-29 23:53:53 UTC"
[4] "1995-08-29 23:54:15 UTC" "1995-08-29 23:54:16 UTC" "1995-08-29 23:54:18 UTC"
[7] "1995-08-29 23:54:19 UTC" "1995-08-29 23:54:19 UTC"
```

**Data**

```
vec <- c("[29:23:53:25]", "[29:23:53:36]", "[29:23:53:53]", "[29:23:54:15]", 
"[29:23:54:16]", "[29:23:54:18]", "[29:23:54:19]", "[29:23:54:19]")
```